# "aspektas strange" aŭ "aspektas stranga"?

Tags: word-formation

En la traduko de Zamenhof de "Fabeloj de Anderson", oni povas trovi:

"Tio aspektis tre bele, precipe kiam la turbo turniĝis."

kaj ankaŭ:

"Unu vesperon la cikonia patro iom tro longe estis eksterdome, kaj kiam li venis hejmen, li aspektis tre ekscitita kaj rapidema."

Kial li uzis "-e" sufikson en la unua ekzemplo, kaj "-a" sufikson en la dua?

Answer (score 10):

Tutan respondon vi trovos en [Priskribaj verboj en PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/specialaj_priskriboj/perverba/subjekto.html#i-gia).

> Perverba priskribo (kun A-vorto) kaj maniera komplemento (kun E-vorto), estas egale ĝustaj ĉe aspekti, kaj tre ofte apenaŭ gravas, kiun formon oni elektas.

Kelkfoje povas tamen esti nuanco:

> La domo aspektas bona. = La aspekto de la domo montras, ke ĝi (verŝajne) estas bona.

> La domo aspektas bone. = La aspekto de la domo estas bona.

En tiuj frazoj de Zamenhof,

> Tio aspektis tre bele

temas pri **lia aspekto**, dum

> li aspektis tre ekscitita kaj rapidema.

temas pri **li**.

En tiu paĝo oni mencias `senti sin` kiel similan verbon:

- Mi sentas min bone = mi fartas bone, nenio doloras, ...
- Mi sentas min bona = mi sentas, ke mi estas bona

Comment: Dankon, nun mi komprenas.